# Python — Opening multiple tabs that can be automatically interacted with simultaneously using chrome webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tabs

I'm using Python to code a Kahoot flooder and need to open a user specified amount of tabs at the same time (bot amount). I also want to be able to interact with all of these tabs simultaneously or in a very short amount of time. Here is my code:

```
import time, selenium, Typewriter, random
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

Typewriter.typewriter("KahootBummer Version 1.0" "\n")
botamount = input("How Many Bots Do You Want?" "\n")
botamount = int(botamount)
pin = input("Please Enter Game Pin" "\n")
pin = int(pin)
name = input("Please Enter A Name" "\n")

for i in range(botamount):

    namenum = random.randint(0,2347324)
    namenum = str(namenum)
    name = str(name) + namenum

    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("-incognito")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/boomb/Desktop/Finished Python 
    Programs/chromedriver.exe",options=chrome_options)
    driver.get("https://kahoot.it/")
    time.sleep(2)

    pinenter = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='game-input']")
    pinenter.click()
    pinenter.send_keys(pin)

    entergame = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Enter')]")
    entergame.click()
    time.sleep(2)

    nameenter = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='nickname']")
    nameenter.click()
    nameenter.send_keys(name)

    okaygo = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'OK, go!')]")
    okaygo.click()
```

Basically I want it to run this loop a set amount of times in a short period of time without having to wait for each loop to finish. Also I am new to coding so sorry for messy code. Thank you!

Comment: Essentially, as far as I know, this is not possible because actions conducted by webdriver are not thread-safe. You could try to introduce multithreading but it might not behave properly. Why is it you are needing to only use *one* chromedriver?

Comment: Hey thanks for answering, Say if I wanted to use have 100 tabs (100 bots) would I need 100 chromedriver instances?

Comment: If you want to simultaneously and reliably control all of those tabs then yes, I think so.

Comment: How would I do that, very new to python and only been using selenium for a day. any tutorials for that? really not sure how to search for that or implement it in my current code, most people making this sort of flooder bot use Node.js but I haven't gotten around to learning that yet.

Comment: So, except that you want it to execute faster, what is wrong with your current code? It looks like maybe you are missing the piece to open the new tab, and cause each loop to execute in a new tab? But the way it looks like right now, a new chromedriver should initialize each loop, although I expect that would be in a new window, not a tab.

Comment: Yeah, because when I currently run it it opens a new window after the original loop finishes. Once it opens a new window it cannot interact with the previous window, only the most recently opened window, I pretty much need to have the loop run over multiple headless tabs/windows at the same time or with very little delay.